# Authentication error when integrating Microsoft teams using graph into angular

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a sample angular project using the graph tutorial. My requirement is to integrate Microsoft teams into an angular application. Using the sample project I can login using the microsoft credentials. Below code is for the access token retrieval.

```js
 async getAccessToken(): Promise<string> {
    const result = await this.msalService
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: OAuthSettings.scopes
      })
      .toPromise()
      .catch((reason) => {
        this.alertsService.addError('Get token failed', JSON.stringify(reason, null, 2));
      });

    if (result) {
      return result.accessToken;
    }

    // Couldn't get a token
    this.authenticated = false;
    return '';
  }
```

and this is my Oauth Settings

```js
export const OAuthSettings = {
  appId: Application (client) ID from Azure portal,
  redirectUri: 'http://localhost:4200',
  scopes: [
    "user.read",
    "mailboxsettings.read",
    "calendars.read",
    "OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite"
  ]
};
```

this is the code using to create the meeting

```js
private graphClient: Client;
constructor(private authService: AuthService) {

  // Initialize the Graph client
  this.graphClient = Client.init({
    authProvider: async (done) => {
      // Get the token from the auth service
      const token = await this.authService.getAccessToken()
        .catch((reason) => {
          done(reason, null);
        });

      if (token)
      {
        done(null, token);
      } else {
        done("Could not get an access token", null);
      }
    }
  });
}
async createCall() {
    const onlineMeeting = {
      startDateTime: '2021-07-20T07:30:34.2444915-07:00',
      endDateTime: '2021-07-20T15:30:34.2444915-07:00',
      subject: 'User Token Meeting'
    };
    
    await this.graphClient.api('/me/onlineMeetings').post(onlineMeeting);
  }
```

but when I call the above function createCall(), I get 400 on and below is the response

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthenticationError",
        "message": "Error authenticating with resource",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-07-20T00:37:47",
            "request-id": request-id,
            "client-request-id": client-request-id
        }
    }
}
```

also the token api gets called,
`Request URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`
which gives the response

```json
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "scope": "User.Read MailboxSettings.Read Calendars.Read openid profile",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "ext_expires_in": 3600,
    "access_token": access_token,
    "refresh_token": refresh_token,
    "id_token": id_token,
    "client_info": client_info
}
```

so in the above response it is not showing the online meeting scope I have passed in Oauth Settings.

This is the api permission given to the application in Azure portal

1. OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite      Delegated    Read and create user's online meetings
2. OnlineMeetings.ReadWrite.All  Application  Read and create online meetings
3. User.Read                     Delegated    Sign in and read user profile

Comment: Would you share the request-id so we can look into this?

Comment: @Diana request-id of the last error, b4ef5b72-f066-409d-8bf0-87718afdabd6